# Prioridades do Código em C#

Tags: c#, paralelismo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProgramacaoParalela
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pressione ENTER para iniciar");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Invocar os métodos que vamos executar
            Parallel.Invoke(
            new Action(exibirCarros),
            new Action(exibirFarol)
            );

            // Aguardar a continuação do programa
            Console.WriteLine("\nO método Main foi encerrado. Tecle Enter");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void exibirCarros()
        {
            string[] carrosArray = { "Ambulancia", "Bombeiros", "Policia", "Passeio" };
            foreach (string carro in carrosArray)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Carro: {0}", carro);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        static void exibirFarol()
        {
            string[] farolArray = { "Verde", "Amarelo", "Vermelho" };

            foreach (string farol in farolArray)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Farol : {0}", farol);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

No meu código acima, apos a execução preciso que o carro "passeio" pegue algum farol de preferencia o farol verde e na execução do código ele não fica com nenhum farol! para esse código ficar repetindo preciso de um laço tipo o while, porém ao adicioná-lo no código aparece uma mensagem de erro, preciso chamar alguma classe que o tenha ou mudar algum parâmetro do código?